# How do you persist environment variables in VSCode?

Tags: amazon-web-services, variables, visual-studio-code, command-line-interface, environment

On Windows, in the VSCode Terminal (which I believe is Powershell), I am attempting to work with the aws cli, and as part of that, I need to setup and refer to a profile that has credentials to connect to my AWS account.  A month or so ago, I was using a profile named xxxx_AWSAdministratorAccess (where xxxx is my AWS account number), and all was working as expected.  Today, I want to use different credentials, so I setup a new profile named CICD.  If I set my profile using the `aws configure` command, it will work for that session.  However if I create a new Terminal session, or start a new instance of VSCode, it reverts back to the xxxx_AWSAdministratorAccess profile.

I noticed in the Terminal there is an environment variable named AWS_PROFILE and this is set to xxxx_AWSAdministratorAccess.  I have changed this using `$env:AWS_PROFILE = 'CICD'` as well as `[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('AWS_PROFILE','CICD')`.  Both work as they set the environment variable to CICD, and the latter command is supposed to persist the value according to what I read.  It sort of works as I can open up a PowerShell session away from VSCode and it will also report the correct AWS profile, but as soon as I close the VSCode Terminal and re-open it reverts back to the xxxx_AWSAdministratorAccess value.  It appears VSCode or an extension or something is caching this value, but I can't figure out where.  Thoughts?

Comment: what if you start VSC from a terminal that has the correct value for the variable, have you looked in the OS version of environment variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the comment from @rioV8 above, I opened a new Powershell window, set the AWS_PROFILE to CICD, and then launched VSCode from there.  When I launched a new Terminal window inside VSCode, and ran `dir env:` the AWS_PROFILE variable was still set to CICD, so that is interesting.  I then went to the Environment Variables in Control Panel and deleted AWS_PROFILE.  I then re-launched VSCode and the environment variable is no longer there, and the `aws configure` command works as expected to update the profile.

So...long story short, I am not sure where that AWS_PROFILE environment variable came from, but deleting it as opposed to updating the value to something else, seems to have resolved my issue.  Thanks for the suggestion!